# How to add docs to Solr using PHP?

Tags: php, solr

I've got Solr set up on my server, and a test collection loaded.

Without installing anything else, I can search the collection fine using the Solr URL and JSON decoding `file_get_contents($url)`.

In order to add/update/delete documents, do I need to install a PHP Solr client? Or is there a native way that is standard to use? If the former, is this the one to install?: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php - or can you recommend another and why?

Comment: I found SOLARIUM to be extremely helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below links :

[Integrate SOLR - wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/IntegratingSolr)

[SOLR PHP - Official Client Library](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolPHP)

[Link to download SOLR php client library](http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/downloads/detail?name=SolrPhpClient.r60.2011-05-04.zip&can=2&q=)

Answer (score 1):

In my company we've been successfully using the native Solr client for PHP that you've mentioned for a while now. I also found Solarium helpful, however it has it's limitations, so it might be worth looking into using HTTP request tools like Guzzle, Httpful and such.