# Are PECL & solarium mandatorily required to run solr on php?

Tags: php, solr, pecl, solarium

Well i have tried finding documents on starting solr with php but couldn't any proper startup guide for beginners. Some places it just mentions solr client libraries, some mention pecl and some mention solarium too. Are all the three required?
And if not , on what basis can a beginner decide what is required to run solr on php.

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695675/php-and-solr-a-little-guidance-for-setting-up-adding-docs-please/19700469#19700469

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually [**Pecl**](http://pecl.php.net/package/solr), **solarium** and **solr-php-client**,all of them are client libraries that will help you to deal with, and use Solr.

So they do the same job. and they are not all required, you just need to choose one that fits the more with your needs/preferences.

-Pecl is a php extension wich means that it will extend php like every other extension like curl ..., i would recommand it because it is a light weight and well documentated and always updated.

-Solarium is a third party librarry which is like a poject that you can run it on it's own and it is recommended too and well documented you find examples of it uses every where.

-solr-php-client is a third party library too, there are no more updates since 2011 but it is also used and well known.

So In more simple words:
if you want to use solr with php you choose one of libraries mensionned below, and then you install it,and finally use it.
I'd recommand that you use pecl extension because it will be installed once on your machine not just n the project.
Solarium too is a very good choice and well recommended but for a beginner try pecl.
you could find the documentation on the official sie of PHP(http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php).

And if you want any other help or expanation you're welcome.